# User input timeout in Windows PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, input, timeout

I need a timeout for any user input in ISE. `$Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable` is possibly not working in ISE. Is there another way to do this?

```
$sleepSeconds = 5
$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds $sleepSeconds
$stopWatch = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

while ($stopWatch.Elapsed -lt $timeout)
{
    if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable) 
    {
        $keyPressed = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho, IncludeKeyUp, IncludeKeyDown")
        if ($keyPressed.KeyDown -eq "True") 
        { 
            break 
        }                
    } 
}
```

Comment: All sources on this topic imply that "$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()" is disabled in PSISE by design. (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0787bcba-f977-400d-8b62-57ec64a71a8a/why-do-i-get-an-exception-calling-readkey?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: @CraftyB Maybe `$userInput = Read-Host "Enter some data: "` or something is working then?